# Launching a process using pysphere in activatedWindow mode

Tags: pysphere

When I launch various processes on VM's on my ESXi server the default opening style of any process is minimize,i.e the window is not activated. Does anyone know how to activate that window using pysphere?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where's your code?

Comment: actually there is a method predefined in pysphere which starts the process,i.e  vm.start_process(process_name,[args],cwd,interactive=True) where vm is the virtal machine's instance.